# function to remove duplicate strings in Clips

Tags: string, clips

Exists in Clips, an  function to remove duplicate strings?
Example: I have this structure:

> ```
> [quality] [comfort] [caliber] [console]
> [quality] [comfort] [caliber] [console]
> [quality] [comfort] [character] [console]
> [quality] [comfort] [lineament] [console]
> [quality] [comfort] [timbre] [console]
> ```

and I need to keep only one [quality] [comfort]. These are stored in variables as follows:
"[" ?tpe1 "]" "[" ?tpic1 "]" "[" ?syntype "]" "[" ?syntopic "]"

These is code that to writes in a file:

> ```
> (defrule Synonymous::rulesoftgoal " "
> (declare (salience 55))
> (synonymoustype
> (type            ?type    )
> (syntype         ?syntype ))
> (synonymoustopic
> (topic           ?topic   )
> (syntopic        ?syntopic))
> =>
> (printout  baseFile "[" ?tpe1 "]" "["?tpic1"]""[" ?syntype"]" "[" ?syntopic "]" crlf) 
> )
> ```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

If this is your original approach:

```
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate synonymoustype
   (slot id)
   (slot type)
   (slot syntype))
CLIPS>    
(deftemplate synonymoustopic
   (slot id)
   (slot topic)
   (slot syntopic))
CLIPS>    
(deffacts initial
   (synonymoustype (id 1) (type quality) (syntype caliber))
   (synonymoustype (id 2) (type quality) (syntype caliber))
   (synonymoustype (id 4) (type quality) (syntype character))
   (synonymoustype (id 4) (type quality) (syntype linament))
   (synonymoustype (id 5) (type quality) (syntype timbre))
   (synonymoustopic (id 6) (topic comfort) (syntopic console)))
CLIPS> 
(defrule rulesoftgoal
   (declare (salience 55))
   (synonymoustype
      (type ?type)
      (syntype ?syntype ))
   (synonymoustopic
      (topic ?topic)
      (syntopic ?syntopic))
   =>
   (printout t "[" ?type "]" " [" ?topic "]" " [" ?syntype "]" " [" ?syntopic "]" crlf))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
[quality] [comfort] [caliber] [console]
[quality] [comfort] [caliber] [console]
[quality] [comfort] [character] [console]
[quality] [comfort] [linament] [console]
[quality] [comfort] [timbre] [console]
CLIPS>
```

Here's one way to prevent duplicates from being printed:

```
CLIPS>    
(deftemplate synonymoustype
   (slot id)
   (slot type)
   (slot syntype))
CLIPS>    
(deftemplate synonymoustopic
   (slot id)
   (slot topic)
   (slot syntopic))
CLIPS>    
(deffacts initial
   (synonymoustype (id 1) (type quality) (syntype caliber))
   (synonymoustype (id 2) (type quality) (syntype caliber))
   (synonymoustype (id 4) (type quality) (syntype character))
   (synonymoustype (id 4) (type quality) (syntype linament))
   (synonymoustype (id 5) (type quality) (syntype timbre))
   (synonymoustopic (id 6) (topic comfort) (syntopic console)))
CLIPS> 
(defrule rulesoftgoal
   (declare (salience 55))
   (synonymoustype
      (type ?type)
      (syntype ?syntype ))
   (synonymoustopic
      (topic ?topic)
      (syntopic ?syntopic))
   =>
   (assert (print-string (str-cat "[" ?type "]" " [" ?topic "]" " [" ?syntype "]" " [" ?syntopic "]"))))
CLIPS> 
(defrule rulesoftgoal-print
   ?f <- (print-string ?string)
   =>
   (retract ?f)
   (printout t ?string crlf))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
[quality] [comfort] [timbre] [console]
[quality] [comfort] [linament] [console]
[quality] [comfort] [character] [console]
[quality] [comfort] [caliber] [console]
CLIPS>
```

And here's another:

```
CLIPS>    
(deftemplate synonymoustype
   (slot id)
   (slot type)
   (slot syntype))
CLIPS>    
(deftemplate synonymoustopic
   (slot id)
   (slot topic)
   (slot syntopic))
CLIPS>    
(deffacts initial
   (synonymoustype (id 1) (type quality) (syntype caliber))
   (synonymoustype (id 2) (type quality) (syntype caliber))
   (synonymoustype (id 4) (type quality) (syntype character))
   (synonymoustype (id 4) (type quality) (syntype linament))
   (synonymoustype (id 5) (type quality) (syntype timbre))
   (synonymoustopic (id 6) (topic comfort) (syntopic console)))
CLIPS> 
(defrule rulesoftgoal
   (declare (salience 55))
   (synonymoustype
      (type ?type)
      (syntype ?syntype ))
   (synonymoustopic
      (topic ?topic)
      (syntopic ?syntopic))
   (not (already-printed ?type ?topic ?syntype ?syntopic))
   =>
   (assert (already-printed ?type ?topic ?syntype ?syntopic))
   (printout t "[" ?type "]" " [" ?topic "]" " [" ?syntype "]" " [" ?syntopic "]" crlf))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
[quality] [comfort] [caliber] [console]
[quality] [comfort] [character] [console]
[quality] [comfort] [linament] [console]
[quality] [comfort] [timbre] [console]
CLIPS>
```